# Prime or composite calculator errors when I enter a composite number

Tags: python, primes

```
num = int(input("Enter A NUMBER: "))

def primeornot():
  for i in range(2, num//2):
    if (num % i) == 0:
      print(num, "is not a prime number")
    elif (num % i) != 0:
      print("Its prime!")
    
primeornot()
```

Try entering a composite number, such as 55, it will print many results. It will say that it is not prime, and then say that it is prime.

Comment: You're printing the output in a loop. Are you expecting a single result because that's not how you've coded it

Comment: You can't know that the number is prime until you get to the end of the loop without finding a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use break if it satisfies if condition and else block if it is prime

```
num = int(input("Enter A NUMBER: "))

def primeornot():
  for i in range(2, num//2):
    if (num % i) == 0:
      print(num, "is not a prime number")
      break
  else:
      print("Its prime!")
    
primeornot()
```